# Salesforce API: Creating EmailMessage and associating a Contact possible?

Tags: python, api, salesforce

I'm working on a project where (already sent) emails should be saved to Salesforce and matched with the corresponding Salesforce contact.

Creating new Emails is rather straightforward. For example using the simple_salesforce python library my code looks like this:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

[…]

sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url, session_id=session_id)
sf.EmailMessage.create(
    {'FromAddress': 'foo@example.com',
     'ToAddress': 'bar@example.com',
     'Subject': 'Email: Fancy Subject', 
     'TextBody': 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',  
     'Status': 2
    })
```

This successfully creates a new EmailMessage but the message is not matched to the contact (assuming bar@example.com is an exisiting contact in Salesfored). This can be seen in numerous places in the Salesforce UI. For example:

- It is not part of the contact's activity history
- When looking at the Email Message details, the section “Sender and Recipients” is empty

When creating new emails using the Salesforce UI, the association is done correctly. Comparing my `EmailMessage` objects from the ones generate by Salesforce there is one obvious difference: `ActivityId` is not set for my objects.

When I'm trying to set `ActivityId` I receive a Malformed Request Exception `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY`.

Is it somehow possible to create those associations using the API?

Comment: Hy did you find some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, you can set this mail as an attachment to the contact. Or best if you have a custom object storing the mails.

If you're planning to use an attachment, give parentId as contact Id.

If you're planning to create a custom object, set contact object as a lookup column(a relationship type in salesforce), which will allow you to set contact ID for the newly created column.

**PS - EmailMessage is another type of object, it can't be stored.**

Comment: Thanks! This works if you are the admin of the SF organization, but is unfortunately not a feasible solution for a customer integration.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

a) While creating the email message object, pass `ToIds`, `CcIds`, `BccIds` instead of `ToAddress`, `CcAddress`, … when the contact exists in SF.

b) Unfortunately there is no `FromIds` field. So for the sender of the email message, this can be resolved by creating an `EmailMessageRelation` afterwards. E.g.:

```
sf.EmailMessageRelation.create({
                'EmailMessageId': email_message_id, # id of the email message created before
                'RelationAddress': from_contact_address, # sender email address
                'RelationId': from_relation_id, # SF Human object ID (in my case user id or contact id)
                'RelationType': 'FromAddress'
            })
```

Comment: May I ask how you set `ToIds`, `CcIds` and `BccIds`? I thought they should be Python strings but my request keeps failing...